# How to print Point (openCV) value?

Tags: c++, opencv, point

Is this possible to print Point value?

For the example, I have a Point like this:

```
Point coordinate = Point(150,300);
```

And I want to show its value. I tried several ways, like:

first:

```
cout << coordinate << "\n";
```

second:

```
cout << coordinate.x << coordinate.y << "\n";
```

I also try the suggestion to flush it, become:

```
std::cout << coordinate << std::endl;
```

But none of those are work in my case. Is there any suggestion? Thanks for your help.
Ps. I work with opencv 3 and c++

Comment: Try flushing at the end. `std::cout << std::flush;`

Comment: I already try it, but it still didn't work @MateenUlhaq

Comment: Try replacing the line `cout << coordinate.x << coordinate.y << "\n";` with `cout << 150 << 300 << "\n";`. If it still doesn't work, we know OpenCV is definitely not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << coordinate.x << "," << coordinate.y << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.